# Can we use for loop with switch statement..?

Tags: java, for-loop, switch-statement

I am trying to iterate for loop by using switch statement. I want to print particular data from that switch statement.

I am taking data in one array, like 5,6 and i am iterating loop with this array length by switch statement. it should print 5 and 6th values only from switch statement. But it's not working.

it's giving below out put::::

Concatination of String value
Print 11
Concatination of String value
Print 1

```
public class String_Concat {

public void concat(int n){
    System.out.println("Concatination of String value");

     switch (n)
        {
            case 1 : 
                System.out.println("Print 1");
                break;
            case 2 : 
                System.out.println("Print 2");
                break;
            case 3 : 
                System.out.println("Print 3");
                break;
            case 4 : 
                System.out.println("Print 4");
                break;
            case 5 : 
                System.out.println("Print 5");
                break;
            case 6 : 
                System.out.println("Print 6");
                break;
            case 7 :
                System.out.println("Print 7");
                break;
            case 8 :
                System.out.println("Print 8");
                break;
            case 9 : 
                System.out.println("Print 9");
                break;
            case 10 : 
                System.out.println("Print 10");
                break;

            default :
                System.out.println("Print 11");

        }
}

public static void main(String[] rags){
    String[] nums={"5","6"};
    String_Concat st=new String_Concat();
    for(int i=0;i<nums.length;i++){
        st.concat(i);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: sure, why not, but you are somewhat writing a lot of obsolete code, and not doing what the comment states (String concatenation)

Comment: a switch is not an iteration, and a switch can only compare against one value

Comment: I think you meant to write `st.concat(Integer.parseInt(nums[i]));`

Comment: Sweeper is right. you are currently passing the indices of those elements, which are 0 and 1. 0 will print 11, 1 will print 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should change the loop like this:

```java
for(int i=0;i<nums.length;i++){
            st.concat(Integer.valueOf(nums[i]));
        }
```

In your code you are calling this:

```
st.concat(0);
st.concat(1);
```

so the output is right.

Answer (score 1):

**Where you have it wrong**

Your issue is in the below:

```
for(int i=0;i<nums.length;i++){
    st.concat(i);
}
```

You're passing in the counter as the argument, i.e. `st.concat(0)`, which then goes into the `default:` option in your switch statement, printing out a value of `11`. In the second iteration you are passing in `st.concat(1)` which prints out a value of `1`.

**How to Fix**

You should instead pass in `nums[i]`, which returns you a `5` in the first iteration.

Also, because your `concat` method accepts an `int`, you need to do a quick conversion:
`st.concat(Integer.parseInt(nums[i]));`

To make it simpler, just declare and populate `nums` as an array of `int` instead:

```
int[] nums= { 5, 6 };
```

Comment: Use `parseInt`, not `valueOf` (they parse to primitive and wrapped, respectively).

Answer (score 0):

Let us first understand what's going on in this code . In the first iteration the value of **i** is 0, with which it goes to concat method and it tries to match against the switch cases but it finds none (as the cases are from 1 to 9) and goes for default case and hence prints **print 11** . After that in second iteration the value of **i** becomes 1 and it again goes in concat method , where it finds a exact match with case 1 and hence prints **print 1** .

Now to get what you expect from this code , you need to **pass the value of array elements** in each iteration of *for loop*. And also you need to convert the values of nums from string to integer as your method expects **int** datatype.

> st.concat(Integer.parseInt(nums[i]))